# Swift google autocomplete with local search

Tags: ios, swift3, autocomplete, google-places

I am trying to do Google Autocomplete using Google Places in Swift 3.0. But I need to search depending upon my current location. Example, **If I am in Kolkata, India and I type search keyword "Ko" it will show the results of Kolkata first** .

Can anyone help me.
Here is my code.**I import GooglePlaces in my class**

```
@IBAction func txtFieldLocationDidStartEditing(_ sender: Any) {   
  self.placeAutocomplete()
}
func placeAutocomplete() {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
       autocompleteController.delegate = self
   present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

// MARK: - autoComplete Delegates

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

Please anyone help me to solve it out. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could supply the API with your mapview's bounding box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only API provided by `GMSAutocompleteViewController` is to set the `GMSCoordinateBounds` like so ([reference](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller.html#a65482d86732910ff07a2827b6d181dc5)):

```
func placeAutocomplete() {
    let visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.farLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.nearRight)

    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.autocompleteBounds = bounds
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nathan , Setting up bounds is working fine.